# What does Islam exclusively say about human sacrifice?

Tags: human-body, judaism, sacrifice

**What does Islam exclusively say about human sacrifice? By exclusively, I mean excluding what is already said in Judaism and Christianity.**

So, I guess anything newly added to the texts during or after Prophet Muhammad (PBUH).

Comment: This is a much better question without the irrelevant misinformation. I'm guessing that the current down-votes were because of that, so I'll add a +1. (It's unfortunate that edits can't get up-votes.)

Answer (score -1):

### Before Muhammad (p.b.u.h)

There is evidence that some pagan Arabs killed their own children.

A tradition says that [Abd al-Muttalib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abd_al-Muttalib), grandfather of Muhammad (p.b.u.h), wowed to sacrifice a child if he had 10 sons but when he had ten sons, he did not want to keep his wow, so he sacrificed camels instead (summary can be read on the cited Wikipedia article). This illustrates that killing children was not only an act of desperation committed by people who feared not to be able to nourish their children but human sacrifice was not yet eradicated before Muhammad (p.b.u.h).

### The Message of the Quran

There are two passages in the Quran that forbid this:

Al-Isra, 17:31-33

> And do not kill your children for fear of poverty. We provide for them, and for you. Killing them is a grave sin. And do not come near adultery. It is immoral, and an evil way. And do not kill the soul which God has made sacred, except in the course of justice. If someone is killed unjustly, We have given his next of kin certain authority. But he should not be excessive in killing, for he will be supported.

Al-Anam 6:140

> Lost are those who kill their children foolishly, with no basis in knowledge, and forbid what God has provided for them—innovations about God. They have gone astray. They are not guided.

### Rulings on killing

In Islam, it is forbidden to kill a person except for prescribed penalty and in a war against an agression of the enimies of Islam ([jihad war](https://islamqa.org/maliki/binbayyah/29832/illusions-misconceptions-about-islam/)). It is so  clear to all Mulsim that God does not want a ritual sacrifice of a human that it need not be mentioned in scholarly fiqh. Even animal sacrifice is limited to [Eid ul-Adha](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/darulihsan/76706/qurbani-the-significance-of-udhiyya/) only.

### Rulings on self-sacrifice

Islam allows (welcomes) that a person sacrifices his *own* life in a jihad war.

It is also well-received if someone endagers and finally sacrifices his life trying to save the lives of others.

It is also correct to confess to ask for penalty before a court if someone has committed a capital sin.

In all other cases, it is forbidden (haram) to put an end to ones own life (commit [suicide](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/muftionline/129145/committing-suicide-2/)). Said this, a ritual self-sacrifice is forbidden, too.

### Sacrifice of Non-Muslims

Some terrorists acting in the name of Islam are reported to have performed a kind of [ceremonial killing of Non-Muslims](https://shoebat.com/2013/07/02/human-sacrifice-public-executions-and-mob-rule-in-the-middle-east/) (I am not sure whether the linked is reliable, and the video references are no longer available).

All [Orthodox](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/10915/why-is-it-that-when-a-muslim-mentions-to-another-that-its-ok-to-kill-a-jew-or-a-christian-if-the-attack-islam-they-say-thats-not-allowed-islam-what-is-really-allowed/) as well as educated [Salfiya](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/82360/muslims-opinion-of-christians-is-the-jihad-that-they-spoke-of-in-the-past-still-ongoing) scholars deny the right to kill Non-Muslim except during a jihad war (a war of Non-Muslims waged against Muslims). A ceremonial killing of disbelievers is a transgression of the Sharia, and forbidden (haram) in Islam.

Comment: That's about killing children in general, not human sacrifice(like maybe due to poverty). Say how the bible tells you to 'love your neighbour', but tells you to kill him if he works on the sabbath etc.

Comment: And as for terrorists they are committing Jihad, so is it okay for them to kill?

Comment: Terrorists have no right to declare their actions jihad. They think they have but they haven't.

Comment: I am not the one to explain or defend Torah based Halacha. Better ask on Judaism de.

Comment: @Kamikira You don't seem to have any sensible definition of human sacrifice. Are crimes which are punished with execution like murder and adultery while married considered human sacrifice to you?

Comment: @TheZ Sorry! That's not what I mean. What I meant is love your neighbor has exceptions. You aren't always supposed to love your neighbor. In the same way  don't kill your children needs context and in this case OP have provided it. Don't kill because of poverty or verses saying don't kill doesn't mean don't do human sacrifice. OP has taken the quote out of context. For all we know the authors of these verses could consider human sacrifice justified like the Old testament authors did.

Comment: To solve this issue, we need verses specifically talking about human sacrifice and not vague verses like "Don't kill" in general or "Don't kill out of poverty". In any language any command given by anyone is not absolute, because languages can't capture feelings accurately. Similar to how love your neighbor has exceptions.

Comment: Consider the verses stated above. "Don't kill" or "Don't kill the young because of poverty". Even this has exceptions. You shouldn't assume it means never kill right. Islam considers killing in many cases to be justifialbe. For example killing because of apostasy. Should you use these verses to spare apostates? No, right? Similarly we don't know if Islam considers Human Sacrifice to be justifiable. And in this case Judaism verses which are part of Islam consider Human Sacrifice to be justifiable. Unless we see verses about Human Sacrifice to be wrong we have to assume the Judaism verses right

Comment: @Kamikira Judaism is not considered a source of law for us. The general law about killing is that it is forbidden except for specific exceptions that are clearly mentioned in the Quran or Sunnah. If there is no exception there, it is forbidden. That's how the law works. We don't particularly care what Judaism says.

Comment: There is an answer on Judaism se here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/133244/24085. I have asked for you.

Comment: You should make a difference between human sacrifice (humans offered to appease a deity - 100% forbidden in Islam) and penalty law which includes death penalty in three cases. Death penalty for apostasy is disputed as the only hadith supporting it contradicts other hadith and evidence from the Quran. But as said before, such is not a discussion on human sacrifice but on righteous penalty law.

Comment: @Kamikira Unrelated to your main question but Islam doesn't say that one is to be killed if they apostate like a normal killing, they are to be executed. It's from the acts that only can be performed by the governer of a state. So if you see some random guy killing someone because that someone apostated, he is not justified for killing him and is sinful (considered sinful by many scholars, not sure of ijma here or not). The process follows a hearing in the court and decisions made by the government, not random people. Similar applies to most such punishments known as the "hadd" punishments.